# Can not iterate over null error at stdin 18

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, null, devops, jq

Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-196:-$ aws iam list-users | jq.Reservations[].functions[].UserId"

jq: error (at <stdin>:18): Cannot iterate over null (null)

ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-196:-$ aws iam list-users | jq".Reservations[].functions[].UserId'
```

Comment: Either `.Reservations` or `.Reservations[].functions` is `null` (or non-existent) in your input document. Please show it(s relevant parts) by issuing `jq .`

Answer (score 1):

You could sprinkle postfix "?"s in your query, though exactly how will of course depend on your requirements.  Here's an example:

```
jq '.Reservations[]?.functions[]?.UserId'
```

To understand this, note that if E is some jq expression, then `(E)?` is like `try E catch empty`.